# I'm a beginner to python and don't understand what's wrong with my code. I'm using pynput

Tags: python, pynput

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
import time
import random
while True:
    timebetweentypes = random.randint(300, 86400)
    time.sleep(timebetweentypes)
    typed = random.choice('1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9''q''w''e''r''t''y''u''i''o''p''a''s''d''f''g''h''j''k''l''z''x''c''v''b''n''m''Q''W''E''R''T''Y''U''I''O''P''A''S''D''F''G''H''J''K''L''Z''X''C''V''B''N''M''!''"''£''$''%''^''&''*''('')'',''.''<''>''/''?''@'':'';''~''#'"'"
    keyboard.type(typed)
```

**
The word 'keyboard' on line 9 gets highlighted in red and python tells me that it's a syntax error.

Comment: You're missing a `)` on the row before.

Comment: when you see a syntax error on normal looking code on line 9, look at the line above, and work your way backwards. A mistake on a previous line can cause a syntax error later on.

Comment: The air is online 8. It requires a closing bracket at the end.

Answer (score 1):

In the `typed` variable, there must be a comma after each object like:
`'A','B','C','D'`…

Comment: While this is true when using variables, when you have two string-iterals (i.e, strings that are created by quotation-marks) next to each other, they are automatically concatenated. For instance: `"abc" "def" == "abcdef"` will equate to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Close the bracket on the 8th line. Also you've to separate the characters with a comma. A much simpler way to do it is

```
typed = random.choice('1 2 3 4 ... # "'.split())
```

(... represents all the characters you want. I'm just too lazy to type out.)

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `)` at the line behind all the characters. They think you are continuing the line so the final line will not work.

Answer (score 1):

1. On line 8, put commas between the objects in the list.
2. Close the bracket at the end of the list.